# Nested resource id mix-up in member_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I have an action_item on a SupportSession resource 'show' page. Note that this particular resource is nested under SupportAllocation:

```
ActiveAdmin.register SupportSession do
  belongs_to :support_allocation
```

Here's the action_item code for this nested SupportSession resource:

```
  action_item :request_approval, only: :show do
    link_to 'Send to service user', request_approval_support_allocation_support_session_path(resource), method: :patch
  end
```

And the corresponding member_action code:

```
  member_action :request_approval, method: :patch do
    # These commented lines all throw the same error described below
    #raise support_allocation.support_session
    #resource.status = "awaiting_approval"
    #resource.save
    #ServiceUserMailer.send_session_approval_request_email(resource).deliver_now
    redirect_to support_allocation_support_session_path, notice: "Session sent to service user for approval"
  end
```

The action_item button renders correctly on the 'show' page and successfully calls the member_action, however when this happens, it seems that the id of the nested resource (SupportSession id) and its parent (SupportAllocation) get mixed up, resulting in the following exception error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SupportSessionsController#show
Couldn't find SupportSession with 'id'=9 [WHERE `support_sessions`.`support_allocation_id` = ?]
```

Interestingly, in the browser address bar, the URL is now:

```
http://localhost:3000/support_allocations/9/support_sessions/9
```

This is reflected in the parameters shown on the exception caught:

```
Request
Parameters:

{"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"bZvr+kEThv/uri2E/zL/OWkndFmiQ+7FcGMD6fY3EQrh6d0vNqUaNvc0tC9BJliUYAyF4lxV+8/4T24YxQWzNg==", "support_allocation_id"=>"9", "id"=>"9"}
```

Which shows that the id of the support_session (9) has become mixed up with the support_allocation_id (which should be 6 in this particular case). Consequently the method/association won't work, because support_allocation_id = 9 doesn't exist in my database.

If I run:

```
raise resource.inspect
```

in my action_item, the object appears correct before the member_action is called:

```
#<SupportSession id: 9, venue: "Cafe", start_time: "2019-05-15 16:12:00", end_time: "2019-05-15 16:35:00", status: "unapproved", created_at: "2019-08-23 09:11:05", updated_at: "2019-08-23 09:11:05", support_allocation_id: 6>
```

Any ideas why the member_action isn't getting the right data and throwing the error above? Is this something to do with it being a nested resource?

For your information, this association between the SupportSession and SupportAllocation is reflected in my model:

```
class SupportAllocation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :support_sessions

class SupportSession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :support_allocation
```

Here's the output from rails routes:

```
request_approval_support_allocation_support_session PATCH      /support_allocations/:support_allocation_id/support_sessions/:id/request_approval(.:format) support_sessions#request_approval
   batch_action_support_allocation_support_sessions POST       /support_allocations/:support_allocation_id/support_sessions/batch_action(.:format)         support_sessions#batch_action
                support_allocation_support_sessions GET        /support_allocations/:support_allocation_id/support_sessions(.:format)                      support_sessions#index
                                                    POST       /support_allocations/:support_allocation_id/support_sessions(.:format)                      support_sessions#create
             new_support_allocation_support_session GET        /support_allocations/:support_allocation_id/support_sessions/new(.:format)                  support_sessions#new
            edit_support_allocation_support_session GET        /support_allocations/:support_allocation_id/support_sessions/:id/edit(.:format)             support_sessions#edit
                 support_allocation_support_session GET        /support_allocations/:support_allocation_id/support_sessions/:id(.:format)                  support_sessions#show
                                                    PATCH      /support_allocations/:support_allocation_id/support_sessions/:id(.:format)                  support_sessions#update
                                                    PUT        /support_allocations/:support_allocation_id/support_sessions/:id(.:format)                  support_sessions#update
                                                    DELETE     /support_allocations/:support_allocation_id/support_sessions/:id(.:format)                  support_sessions#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this problem fixed, although I never figured out why the two ids (SupportSession and SupportAllocation) became mixed up.

My solution was to use this code for the action_item:

```
  action_item :send_approval, only: :show, if: proc { support_session.status == 'unapproved' || support_session.status == 'awaiting_approval'} do
    link_to 'Send to service user', send_approval_support_allocation_support_session_path(id: support_session.id, support_allocation_id: support_session.support_allocation.id), method: :patch
  end
```

and this code for the member_action:

```
  member_action :send_approval, method: :patch do
    ServiceUserMailer.send_session_approval_request_email(resource).deliver_now
    resource.status = 'awaiting_approval'
    resource.save
    redirect_to support_allocation_support_session_path, notice: "Session sent to service user for approval"
  end
```

Also, there seemed to be some issue with CanCanCan authorisation, which is probably unrelated but worth mentioning. I granted read/create/update permissions to the current user on SupportSession, but the methods only seemed to work when I granted 'manage' permissions. I then had to revoke the 'destroy' permissions in Ability.rb:

```
  can :manage, SupportSession, support_allocation: { support_worker: {id: user.id }}, status: 'unapproved'
  can :manage, SupportSession, support_allocation: { support_worker: {id: user.id }}, status: 'awaiting_approval'
  cannot :destroy, SupportSession
```

Hope that helps someone.